# Scrolling issue in listview

Tags: android, listview

//Filling the ArrayList From the Fragment

```
gridmodel = new TypeTruckPogo("Truck 14 wheel",-1,false);
        list.add(gridmodel);
        gridmodel = new TypeTruckPogo("Truck 16 wheel",-1,false);
        list.add(gridmodel);

        final TypeOfTruckAdapter truckAdapter=new TypeOfTruckAdapter(context, list);
        truckListView.setAdapter(truckAdapter);
```

//My POGO CLASS

```
public class TypeTruckPogo{
    String typeOfTruckName;
    int nmbrOfTruck;
    boolean isEditTextVisiable;

    public TypeTruckPogo(String typeOfTruckName,int nmbrOfTruck,boolean isEditTextVisiable){
        this.typeOfTruckName=typeOfTruckName;
        this.nmbrOfTruck=nmbrOfTruck;
        this.isEditTextVisiable=isEditTextVisiable;
    }

    public String getTypeOfTruckName() {
        return typeOfTruckName;
    }

    public String setTypeOfTruckName(String typeOfTruckName) {
        this.typeOfTruckName = typeOfTruckName;
        return typeOfTruckName;
    }

    public int getNmbrOfTruck() {
        return nmbrOfTruck;
    }

    public Integer setNmbrOfTruck(int nmbrOfTruck) {
        this.nmbrOfTruck = nmbrOfTruck;
        return nmbrOfTruck;
    }

    public boolean isEditTextVisiable() {
        return isEditTextVisiable;
    }

    public Boolean setIsEditTextVisiable(boolean isEditTextVisiable) {
        this.isEditTextVisiable = isEditTextVisiable;
        return isEditTextVisiable;
    }
}
```

// My Adapter Class,this class have 20 item in the list,at first time it's showing 8 item , when user press on single row then editText become visible and if user press the same position twice the editText become inviable,But the problem is that when user tap on any position(let say he tapped on position 0) then editText is visible but when i scroll down then other editText is also becoming visible sometime position 8 sometime 15.ANY HELP APPRECIATED !!!! Single row contain textView and editText

```
public class TypeOfTruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
List<TypeTruckPogo> list;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public String[] Current;
TypeTruckPogo typeTruckPogo;
public static HashMap<Integer,String> truckHashMap=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
public TypeOfTruckAdapter( Context context,List<TypeTruckPogo> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        truckHashMap.put(i,"");
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}



class Viewholder{
    TextView name;
    EditText nmbrOfTruck;
    int ref;

    Viewholder(View view) {

        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        nmbrOfTruck = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id);
    }

}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
    final Viewholder holder;
    typeTruckPogo = list.get(position);
    if(convertView==null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_for_type_of_truck, parent, false);
        holder = new Viewholder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (Viewholder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    // For position zero i have to set the text color to blue color,else dark gray color
    if(position==0){
        holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
    }else{
        holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
    }
    // setting the name on the textview
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());
    //setting the tag on edittext
    holder.nmbrOfTruck.setTag(position);
    //setting the viewholder position
    holder.ref = position;

   // clicking on listview making edittext to appear (initially edittext is invisiable)
    // if edittext is visiable make it invisiable and if it is invisiable make it visiable
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
    // if user write on editText save the input by the user in specified position
    //truckHashMap is hashmap where I saving the position as a key and value as the user Input

    holder.nmbrOfTruck.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Current = new String[holder.ref];

            truckHashMap.put(position, s.toString().trim());
        }
    });
    // Setting the User Input at specified Position
    holder.nmbrOfTruck.setText(truckHashMap.get(position));

    Config.colorFont(context, null, holder.name, null);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: `position==0` is change every time while you scroll the listview,but if you use some index which related to your model class and place your condition based on that index ,than it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use else statement which set your default text color in your adapter:

```
...
if(position==0){
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
        } else {
          // here set your default text color black for example
          holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black_color));
}
...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You have voted it but not accept. Accepted is when click green tick below vote arrows on my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Now the others people will know that my answer was helped to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107519/discussion-between-ivan-ivanov-and-amit-ranjan).

Comment: I have one more problem while scrolling ,I had updated the code of baseAdapter

Comment: Please create new question, because this is different case, and give mi a link to it and I will answer you. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262388/scrooling-issue-in-listview-when-single-row-contain-textview-and-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Where your `else` condition ?

```
    if(position==0)
    {
              holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
    } else {

    // Calling when if Condition not Satisfied .
             holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor("Your_Color"));
            }
```