# Scrolling issue in Listview when single row contain TextView and EditText

Tags: android, listview

I have a single row which contain `TextView` and `EditText`, Initially `EditText` is invisible,when user tap on single row of `listview` then EditText become visible and if EditText is visible for the Specified position then when user tap again then EditText become invisible.

I am able to make a toggle to a EditText when user Tap,but i don't able to know when EditText is visible and user Scrool then other EditText for some other position is also become visible while Scrolling ,which is not tapped by the user for that position.

```
public class TypeOfTruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    List<TypeTruckPogo> list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public String[] Current;
    TypeTruckPogo typeTruckPogo;
    public static HashMap<Integer,String> truckHashMap=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    public TypeOfTruckAdapter( Context context,List<TypeTruckPogo> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            truckHashMap.put(i,"");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }



    class Viewholder{
        TextView name;
        EditText nmbrOfTruck;
        int ref;

        Viewholder(View view) {

            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            nmbrOfTruck = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        final Viewholder holder;
        typeTruckPogo = list.get(position);
        if(convertView==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_for_type_of_truck, parent, false);
            holder = new Viewholder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Viewholder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        // For position zero i have to set the text color to blue color,else dark gray color
        if(position==0){
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
        }else{
            holder.name.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
        }
        // setting the name on the textview
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getTypeOfTruckName());
        //setting the tag on edittext
        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setTag(position);
        //setting the viewholder position
        holder.ref = position;

       // clicking on listview making edittext to appear (initially edittext is invisiable)
        // if edittext is visiable make it invisiable and if it is invisiable make it visiable
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    v.findViewById(R.id.et_nmbr_of_truck_id).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
        // if user write on editText save the input by the user in specified position
        //truckHashMap is hashmap where I saving the position as a key and value as the user Input

        holder.nmbrOfTruck.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Current = new String[holder.ref];

                truckHashMap.put(position, s.toString().trim());
            }
        });
        // Setting the User Input at specified Position
        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setText(truckHashMap.get(position));

        Config.colorFont(context, null, holder.name, null);
        return convertView;
    }
```

// single_row_for_type_of_truck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
       >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
            android:text="TextView" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_nmbr_of_truck_id"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge_edittext"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:saveEnabled="true"
            android:numeric="integer"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your `single_row_for_type_of_truck.xml` file

Comment: I have posted the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create boolean array which will store visibility state of your edit text. Add this code in your adapter's constuctor:

```
boolean[] isEditTextVisible = new boolean[list.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < isEditTextVisible.length; i++) {
            isEditTextVisible[i] = false;
        }
```

Modify your `getView()` method:

```
    ...

            if (isEditTextVisible[position]){
                holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (holder.nmbrOfTruck.isShown()) {
                        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        isEditTextVisible[position] = false;
                    } else {
                        holder.nmbrOfTruck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isEditTextVisible[position] = true;
                    }

                }
            });
    ...
```

Comment: now it's not coming duplicate but when i scroll up and down ,then the row i clicked and edittext is which become visible for that position is now becoming invisible

Comment: Thanks for the help Ivan,let me try :)

Comment: It's my plasure :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correcly, you could just use a simple `SparseBooleanArray` inside you adapter class that stores whether the 'edit-mode' is active for a certain list position.

To store an activated edit-mode, use `<<YourSparseBooleanArray>>.put(position, true)`.

In your `getView()` method, you have to differentiate whether `<<YourSparseBooleanArray>>.get(position)` returned `true` (=> edit-mode) or `false` (TextView-mode).

And don't forget that views are being recycled, which means you have to set the visibility of your current view in every case when `getView()` is called. (You cannot assume a view is visible if it is passed to `getView()` as `convertView` parameter)